# QTableWidget vertical and horizontal headers becoming invisible

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtablewidget

I've added a table widget to a form and set the vertical and horizontal headers as visible in the property editor. However, they are sometimes invisible during actual execution. If I actually look at the UI file, it shows that the `verticalHeaderVisible` and `horizontalHeaderVisible` attributes are set to false, even though these attributes are set as true in the property editor. Is there another property that's conflicting with them?

Property Editor:

[image: Property Editor]

Result:

[image: Result]

UI File:

[image: UI File]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're affected by [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-12889). There is a response:

> Won't fix. When saving, Designer correctly queries
>   QHeaderView::isVisible() which at that moments returns false although
>   the (header) widget is visible due to some QWidget::isVisible()
>   idiosyncrasy.

So, if your headers somehow become invisible at the moment you save the file, 'false' values will be recorded. I don't know if it really happens in your ui file, but I think it's better not to rely on this strange behaviour. Add these lines to your form class constructor to make headers visible:

```
ui->setupUi(this); // automatically generated
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(true);
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(true);
```